# Custom transform for DateRangeField to query on delta between start and stop dates in Django

Tags: django, django-orm

Question is regarding custom transform or lookup( can’t figure it out yet).

For example I have following model.

```
from django.contrib.postgres.fields import DateRangeField

class Example(models.Model).
    date_range = DateRangeField()
```

Each date_range is a object with start and stop dates, for example [2020-02-24, 2020-04-16)

Question is – is it possible to create a transform or(and) lookup in order to filter instances of model by their range between start date and stop date?

Example

I want to find instances where difference between start and stop date would be more then 1 year.

This would be something like

True - [2020-02-24, 2021-04-16) - delta more then one year

False  -  [2020-02-24, 2020-04-16) - delta less then one year

```
Example.objects.filter(date_range__transform_name_here__gt=365)
```

I can do it via raw SQL but I don’t want to use it as it is quite common task.

Thank you.

Comment: If you are referencing something that not included with Django, good to add it's the reference (In this case, how do we know about `DateRangeField` ?)

Comment: @Arakkal Abu .Added import statement

Answer (score 0):

I know it's probably a bit late to help you, but you should be able to do this to achieve your goal:

```
from django.db.models import DurationField, ExpressionWrapper, F
from django.db.models.functions import Lower, Upper
from django.utils import timezone


greater_than_a_year = Example.objects.all().annotate(
    delta=ExpressionWrapper(
        F('date_range__endswith') - F('date_range__startswith'), output_field=DurationField()
    ).filter(
        delta__gt=timezone.timedelta(days=365)
    )
```

Here we annotate by subtracting the lower portion of the range from the upper, and output as a DurationField() with the name `delta`. Then we simply filter on `delta` like any other DurationField.